# why only 0 values are displaying by using summation equation in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

I have a dataset with three inputs named X1,X2,X3 with date and time. Here for my X3 value I created the summation equation to created the new value in every hour according to the X3 value.

My summation equation is:

[image]

I want to put that A values into numpy array named X
So here I wrote the code to for  the summation equation to create the new data of A :

```
Y = df['X3'].astype(float)
X=list()
for _ in range(len(Y)):
A=0
if Y.all() ==5:
    for i in range(1,16):
        A=np.sum(5)*(i)
elif Y.all() ==7:
    for i in range(1,16):
        A=np.sum(7)*(i)
X.append(A)       
print(X)
```

Then I got only 0 values :

[image]

My data:

```html
date time                x3
10/3/2018 6:00:00         0
10/3/2018 7:00:00         5
10/3/2018 8:00:00         0
10/3/2018 9:00:00         7
10/3/2018 10:00:00 0
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0
10/3/2018 12:00:00 0
10/3/2018 13:45:00 0
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0
10/3/2018 16:00:00 0
10/3/2018 17:00:00 0
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0
10/3/2018 19:00:00 5
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0
10/3/2018 21:30:00 7
10/4/2018 6:00:00         0
10/4/2018 7:00:00         0
10/4/2018 8:00:00    5
10/4/2018 9:00:00         7
10/4/2018 11:00:00 5
10/4/2018 12:00:00 5
10/4/2018 13:00:00 5
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0
10/4/2018 18:00:00 7
10/5/2018 7:00:00         5
10/5/2018 8:00:00         0
```

What my desired output is:

Assume that at 7:00:00 a.m have X3 value 5 . so then by using the summation equation one hour one hour A value will be display using this summation equation till to 16 hrs.

Then assume now X3 have 7 value. So then by using summation equation one hour one hour A value will be display using the summation equation till to 16 hrs.

Like wise what ever the values are in X3 it will add the summation equation then will be run the code.

Comment: Do you want to have the sum of X3 every 16 hours or every day ?

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: @politicalscientist sum of X3 in every 16 hours , is my desired output.

Comment: @DiogenicOrder Here I want to show that starting one hour one hour till to 16 hrs my output value should be calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the desired output, but at least it should get you started.

You first create a datetimeindex from `date` and `time` columns; use `resample` to groupby your datetime index.

```py
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
df.resample('16H').sum()
```

```py
                    x3
2018-10-03 00:00:00 12
2018-10-03 16:00:00 12
2018-10-04 08:00:00 34
2018-10-05 00:00:00 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I have  a question If I want to get the  value in every one hour till to 16 hrs then how to change the code? That's why I thought to use this equation.

Comment: Here I have another inputs data X1,X2 .so when I used this resample data then the other inputs length will be reduced.

Comment: @team you want the cumulative sum aka [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of each 16 hours sample.

It's not clear if you want a rolling window type of things if you want the cumulative sum of every 16hrs block. It's a bit more complicated to do so can you give a small example of what you want to input and what you expect to see.

Comment: @DiogenicOrder Is it okay that I show some example in code in matlab. Here I tried first in matlab code and then I tried to write the code similiarly as this matlab code.

Comment: Well, I won't probably won't be able to help but someone who knows Matlab can surely help you. You should probably edit the original post with the matlab code in order for other people to see the question.

Comment: @NaturalFrequency I will post for python code. I will edit this code